# Django not showing up all fields using objects with select_related

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

i'm facing an annoing bug in Django and i don't know how i can solve it.

I'm trying to show up names from one other table using INNER JOIN but isn't working.

Just to clarify, i have two database **canaisAssoc** and **formatosAssoc**, i'm  trying to show up from canaisAssoc the name of the canais and from formatosAssoc the name of the formato, if you take a look at my views.py, i'm using ajax, because i need to choose one value from one select in template to fill up others, the issue is, when i run the canaisAssoc.objects.select_related('idCanal').filter(idSite_id = site, ativo = True).all()

if i run this

```
print(channels.query)
```

The return of the query is:

SELECT `campanhas_canaisassoc`.`id`, `campanhas_canaisassoc`.`idSite_id`, `campanhas_canaisassoc`.`idCanal_id`, `campanhas_canaisassoc`.`ativo`, `campanhas_canais_dados`.`id`, `campanhas_canais_dados`.`nomeCanais`, `campanhas_canais_dados`.`ativo` FROM `campanhas_canaisassoc` INNER JOIN `campanhas_canais_dados` ON (`campanhas_canaisassoc`.`idCanal_id` = `campanhas_canais_dados`.`id`) WHERE (`campanhas_canaisassoc`.`ativo` = True AND `campanhas_canaisassoc`.`idSite_id` = 3)

If i run this in phpMyAdmin, they are working as expected, showing up all values i'm need it

id|idSite_id|idCanal_id|ativo|id|**nomeCanais**|ativo

However, if i inspect the call of JSON, they are returning this:

{"channel": [{"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 14, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 13, "ativo": true}}, {"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 15, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 1, "ativo": true}}, {"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 16, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 4, "ativo": true}}, {"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 17, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 10, "ativo": true}}, {"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 63, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 30, "ativo": true}}]

Note in the fields there are only 3 values, idSite,idCanal and ativo, nothing i can do in the query returns me the nomeCanais, even using canaisAssoc.objects.raw with que query above doesn't works, any ideas on how i can solve this? below are my codes!

Thanks!

```
Models.py

class Canais_dados(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  nomeCanais = models.TextField()
  ativo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.nomeCanais

class Formatos_dados(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  nomeFormato = models.TextField()
  ativo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.nomeFormato    `Preformatted text`

class canaisAssoc(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  idSite = models.ForeignKey(Sites_dados, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='idSitesCanaisAssoc',null=False)
  idCanal = models.ForeignKey(Canais_dados, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='idCanaisCanaisAssoc',null=False)
  ativo = models.BooleanField(default=True,null=True)  

class formatosAssoc(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  idSite = models.ForeignKey(Sites_dados, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='idSiteFormatoAssoc',null=False)
  idFormato = models.ForeignKey(Formatos_dados, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='idFormatoFormatoAssoc',null=False)
  ativo = models.BooleanField(default=True,null=True)
```

```
views.py

# AJAX
def load_channel(request,site):
  
  channels = canaisAssoc.objects.select_related('idCanal').filter(idSite_id = site, ativo = True).all()
  formats = formatosAssoc.objects.select_related('idFormato').filter(idSite_id = site,ativo = True).all()
  channelName = serialize("json",channels)
  serializedChannel = json.loads(channelName)
  formatName = serialize("json",formats)
  serializedFormat = json.loads(formatName)
  return JsonResponse({'formats':serializedFormat,'channel': serializedChannel})
```

I try objects.raw and even then is not working as expected.

I'm expecting something like that in JSON return:

{"channel": [{"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 14, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 13, "ativo": true,"nomeCanais": "Canal Y"}}, {"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 15, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 1, "ativo": true,"nomeCanais": "CanalXX"}}, {"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 16, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 4, "ativo": true,"nomeCanais": "CanalXXY"}}, {"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 17, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 10, "ativo": true,"nomeCanais": "CanalXXYZ"}}, {"model": "campanhas.canaisassoc", "pk": 63, "fields": {"idSite": 3, "idCanal": 30, "ativo": true,"nomeCanais": "CanalXXYZ"}}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how `select_related` works. It's purpose is to reduce amount of DB requests to get data for related models, not to change their fields.

Consider example:

```python
class ModelA(models.Model):
   a_data = ...  # example field
   ...           # other-fields

class ModelB(models.Model):
   a_object = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, ...)
   b_data = ...  # example field
   ...           # other-fields
```

Without `select_related`:

```python
b_objects = ModelB.objects.all()  # first request

for b in b_objects:
    a = b.a_object     # +1 request for each a_object.
    a_data = a.a_data  # get a_data.
    b_data = b.b_data  # get b_data.
    ...                # do something.
```

Here first request gets data from ModelB's table. Then for each `a_object` an extra request is made to ModelA's table.

With `select_related`:

```python
b_objects = ModelB.objects.select_related('a_object')  # first request.

for b in b_objects:
    a = b.a_object     # no extra requests.
    a_data = a.a_data  # get a_data.
    b_data = b.b_data  # get b_data.
    ...                # do something.
```

Here first request gets ModelB's and related ModelA's data all at once. No extra requests are made. But the way you access that data from the code does not change.

See docs on [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for more details.

Similar method for reverse or m-2-m relations: [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

---

What you need is [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values) + [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/lookups/):

```python
b_objects = ModelB.objects.values(
    'pk',                # b's own fields
    'b_data',            # b's own fields
    'a_object__pk',      # related a_object's fields
    'a_object__a_data',  # related a_object's fields
    ...                  # other fields
)
```

This will return a queryset of dictionaries like this:

```
<QuerySet [
{'pk': 1, 'b_data': 'b_1', 'a_object__pk': 1, 'a_object__a_data': 'a_1'},
{'pk': 2, 'b_data': 'b_2', 'a_object__pk': 2, 'a_object__a_data': 'a_2'},
...]>
```

Then you may serialize it or convert to other data-types before serializing.

Similar method [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) returns lists of values without keys:

```
<QuerySet [
[1, 'b_1', 1, 'a_1'],
[2, 'b_2', 2, 'a_2'],
...]>
```

---

Other way is [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) + [F-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) with field lookups:

```python
b_objects = ModelB.objects.annotate(
    a_pk = F('a_object__pk'),      # add a_object's pk as 'a_pk'
    a_data = F('a_object__data'),  # add a_object's a_data as 'a_data'
)
```

It adds extra properties to `b` objects with corresponding values from related `a` objects.

Combine that with `values` to give keys shorter names:

```python
b_objects = ModelB.objects.annotate(
    a_pk = F('a_object__pk'),      # add a_object's pk as 'a_pk'
    a_data = F('a_object__data'),  # add a_object's a_data as 'a_data'
).values(
    'pk',      # b's own fields
    'b_data',  # b's own fields
    'a_pk',    # annotated fields
    'a_data',  # annotated fields
    ...
)
```

---

[Raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#raw) is not recommended for security reasons.

---

Also consider using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for APIs larger than 1-2 endpoints. It's made just for that.